# Aligning +- sign in table

Tags: tables, align, tabularx

I am creating the following table below with tabularx and I was wondering why the +- sign do not align correctly in the third row and how could I reach an equal separation between the plus and minus sign and numbers (e.g. in the fourth row the spacing is smaller)? Maybe by using siunitx package?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow, longtable, tabularx, makecell}

\newcolumntype{Z}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}X }

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}
 \centering
  \caption{Some test data}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xccc} %{X*{3}{Z}}
\toprule
\thead{Scenario}    &   \thead{$\Delta V$}  &   \thead{$B_{geod.}$} &   \thead{$B_{a (geod.)}$} \\
\midrule
dh\textsubscript{1900-2000}     &   $-471136458\pm752053$   &   -16.57$\pm$1.12 &   -0.41$\pm$0.03  \\
Testrun 1                                       &   $-410517206\pm688309$   &   -17.33$\pm$ 1.16    &   -0.43$\pm$0.03  \\
\midrule
Testrun 2                                       &   $-439038086\pm779176$   &   -16.55$\pm$0.99 &   -0.37$\pm$0.03  \\
Testrun 3                                       &   $-439718460\pm770058$   &   -14.72$\pm$1.00 &   -0.36$\pm$0.03  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
  \label{tab:some example table}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is probably due to the ‘proportional’ digits:  all digits do not have exactly the same width.  You should use the `S` column type from `siunitx`,  which would also turn your hyphens to a true minus sign, and avoid having to type all those `$$`.

Comment: _Maybe by using `siunitx` package?_ Yes, use `S` column type (as mentioned above) for instant magic.

Comment: There is a white space in `-17.33$\pm$ 1.16` There is no white space in the other rows. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For such tables I'd recommend `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,amsmath,caption}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\caption{Some test data}
\label{tab:some example table}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=-9.0(6)]
  S[table-format=-2.2(3)]
  S[table-format=-1.2(1)]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Scenario & {$\Delta V$} & {$B_{\textup{geod.}}$} & {$B_{\textup{a (geod.)}}$} \\
\midrule
dh\textsubscript{1900-2000} & -471136458\pm752053 & -16.57\pm 1.12 & -0.41\pm 0.03  \\
Testrun 1                   & -410517206\pm688309 & -17.33\pm 1.16 & -0.43\pm 0.03  \\
\midrule
Testrun 2                   & -439038086\pm779176 & -16.55\pm 0.99 & -0.37\pm 0.03  \\
Testrun 3                   & -439718460\pm770058 & -14.72\pm 1.00 & -0.36\pm 0.03  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Apart from good alignment, there are other advantages; for instance, omitting the `separate-uncertainty` option, the table would be typeset as follows, with no change in the input.

[image]