# siunitx in tabular and missing space around pm

Tags: tables, formatting, siunitx

The example show the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,multirow}
\sisetup{
    range-phrase = --,
    separate-uncertainty = true,
    retain-zero-uncertainty = true
}
\begin{document}
\num{439 \pm 1} and \num{1.23+-0.02}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Table}
\begin{tabular}{
S
S}
\toprule
439 \pm 4 & 0.53 \pm 0.04  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to achieve the same form with the `S` column as with the `\num` so that there is a nice space around `\pm` in `tabular` as well?

Comment: I'll take a look: could be a missing brace set

Comment: Similar alignment problem as in [Q688397](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/688397).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That one is about numbers using a format: this one uses s different code path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an oversight in the table code, which has to split up the number for typesetting. Here, with no decimal marker/part, the spacing around `\pm` is wrong as it ends up being typeset without any before it. For the present, a fix is

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset:Npn \__siunitx_table_print_marker_aux:w
  #1 \q_nil #2 \q_nil #3 \q_nil #4 \q_nil #5
     \q_nil #6 \q_nil #7 \q_nil #8 \q_stop
  {
    \bool_lazy_and:nnTF
      { \tl_if_blank_p:n {#1#2} }
      { ! \tl_if_blank_p:n {#3} }
      { { } }
      { \exp_not:n {#1#2} }
    \exp_not:n {#3#4#5#6}
    \tl_if_blank:nT {#1#2#3#4#5#6} { { } }
    \exp_not:n {#7#8}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

I will have something to CTAN in a day or so.